# How to add spacing between Bokeh widgets

Tags: bokeh

I was wondering what was the best way to add spacing between widgets in Bokeh ? Right now I am using empty Divs to get some spacing but thats really clumsy, hence the question.

```
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.plotting import figure,show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import DataTable, TableColumn, Div
from bokeh.layouts import row, column
from bokeh.models.widgets import MultiSelect, Button, RadioGroup


def test_view(request):
    # Quick data
    original_data = dict(length=[2, 10, 20, 40, 60, 80, 70, 50, 15, 36, 76, 74, 72, 44, 36, 18, 40, 64, 40, 64, 40, 30, 120],
                         weight=[2, 100, 150, 200, 420, 700, 600, 300, 200, 200, 620, 610, 601, 610, 601, 80, 205, 80, 800, 700, 240, 160, 800])

    original_data = pd.DataFrame(original_data)
    source = ColumnDataSource(original_data)

    # Quick plot
    plot = figure(title = 'title')
    plot.circle(x='length', y='weight', source=source)

    # Quick table
    columns = [TableColumn(field="length", title="length", width=100),
               TableColumn(field="weight", title="weight", width=100)]
    data_table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns)

    # Quick widgets
    some_button = Button(label="button", button_type="success")
    some_radiogroup = RadioGroup(labels=["1", "2"], active=0)
    some_multiselect = MultiSelect(title='multiselect:', value=[], options=[])

    # Spacing
    dumdiv1 = Div(text='', width=10)
    dumdiv2 = Div(text='', width=10)

    widgets_layout = column(some_button, dumdiv1, some_radiogroup, dumdiv2, some_multiselect)
    figures_layout = row(plot, data_table)
    page_layout = row(widgets_layout, figures_layout)

    show(page_layout)
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Widget` class extends the `LayoutDOM` class which has the `margin` attribute.

```py
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot
from bokeh.models import Div


def mk_div(**kwargs):
    return Div(text='<div style="background-color: green; width: 100px; height: 100px;">DIV</div>', **kwargs)


divs = [mk_div(), mk_div(), mk_div(),
        mk_div(), mk_div(margin=(10, 20, 30, 40)), mk_div(),
        mk_div(), mk_div(), mk_div()]

show(gridplot(divs, ncols=3))
```